# Kernel smooth set of xyz tuplets (python preferred pseudocode welcome)

Tags: python, scipy, geometry-surface

I'd like to smooth a set of `xyz` tuplets into a surface and return the value of the `surface(z')` at the original set of of coordinates `(x,y)`.

Is there a more direct approach then interpolating the original data onto a grid, smoothing it and re-evaluating. If that's the best approach, is there python specific functionality that people like / is the standard?

For example:

```
(x1,y1,z1) -> (x1,y1,z1')
(x2,y2,z2) -> (x2,y2,z2')
(x3,y3,z3) -> (x3,y3,z3')
(x4,y4,z4) -> (x4,y4,z4')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Smoothing" is not a well-defined operation; what it means is open to interpretation.   There are many operations that result in "smoother" data, and most of them have at least one parameter that controls the amount of smoothing.  Without knowing more about what you are going to do with the smoothed data, it is hard to give a definitive answer to this question.

Here's an answer anyway. :)

[`scipy.interpolate.Rbf`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html) is an interpolator for n-dimensional data that includes a smoothing parameter.  When this parameter is 0 (which is the default), a true interpolator is created, i.e. it returns the given z values at the given (x, y) values, and at other points it returns interpolated z values.  `Rbf` includes a `smooth` parameter about which the docstring says "Values greater than zero increase the smoothness of the approximation."

So, an answer to your question that uses `Rbf` is:

```
f = Rbf(x, y, z, smooth=<a positive number>)
z_smoothed = f(x, y)
```

(Unfortunately, the `Rbf` docstring doesn't explain how `smooth` is used.  You'd have to dig into the code to find out exactly what it does.  In the meantime, you can try some values and see if the results meet your needs.)

The following script is an example of using `Rbf` with a nonzero `smooth` argument.  The input points and the smoothed surface are plotted using matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


# Generate some random (x, y, z) values.
npoints = 36
np.random.seed(12345)
x, y = np.random.rand(2, npoints)
z = np.cos(3*x)*np.sin(2*y) + 0.4*np.random.randn(npoints)


# "Interpolator" with smoothing
f = Rbf(x, y, z, smooth=0.05)

print("Original z values:")
print(z)
print("Smoothed z values:")
print(f(x, y))

u = np.linspace(0, 1, 25)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(u, u)
zz = f(xx, yy)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z)

surf1 = ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, rstride=1, cstride=1, color='g',
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False, alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

The script generates the following plot.  The blue dots are the original data, and the green surface is the graph of the function created by `Rbf`.

[image: plot]

The script prints:

```
Original z values:
[-0.34127933 -0.30729404  0.21155127  0.82107652  0.17163933 -0.44447561
 -0.62316986 -0.07631452 -0.2452825   0.08006371 -0.16038592 -1.15094797
  0.97879369 -0.59069121  0.28481385 -0.61505364 -1.28958296 -0.40040525
 -0.62065409  0.10887611  0.11082111 -0.57756184 -0.08303365  0.1736536
 -0.11741524 -0.25279036 -0.87523777 -0.62589892  0.14774674  1.02822874
  1.40065013  0.0570847  -1.24442082  1.29216089  0.04075983  0.35829967]
Smoothed z values:
[-0.4760952  -0.32638375  0.33082556  0.81805681  0.04136433 -0.04617472
 -0.6941891  -0.17280308 -0.21626414 -0.25286811 -0.19661876 -1.04547018
  1.19599927 -0.55479106  0.3257578  -0.35879233 -0.9914419  -0.74646378
 -0.60559207 -0.11546096 -0.10684431 -0.35038102  0.05290993  0.10818459
 -0.07302746 -0.33240211 -0.82955756 -0.32360917  0.11565045  0.98144511
  1.22421926 -0.08092414 -0.97381114  1.16754806  0.01186976  0.11594726]
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help, I really appreciate it!